# Rewrite rule error: HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error. The expression "https://abc.com/{R:1}" cannot be expanded

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, url-rewrite-module

Whenever someone makes request over HTTP protocol I rewrite the url to make it HTTPS. This is the code in web.config:

```xml
<rule name="Imported Rule 1-1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(?!https://).*" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="80" ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://abc.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

However when I browse on http:// I get IIS error

> HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error. The expression `"https://abc.com/{R:1}"` cannot be expanded.

How can I resolve this? I am utterly confused.

Comment: I'm getting this also now.  Did you ever find a solution?  If so, please post it here.

Comment: Pssst. You can use `negate="true"` in `match`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The matches are zero based.

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="https://abc.com/{R:1}" />
```

Won't work because you only have one match. You need:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="https://abc.com/{R:0}" />
```

Also, this won't work, because you can only match on the path below the site root.

```
<match url="^(?!https://).*" ignoreCase="false" />
```

It looks like you are checking for ssl. Try this instead:

```
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
```

Comment: While the matches are zero-based, the first match `{R:0}` *always* contains the full string matched, and the second match `{R:1}` matches the *first* capture group within `{R:0}`. So, this answer is incorrect in the first part. You can see for yourself in the "Test Pattern" dialog.

Comment: @jpaugh I wonder if it changed in the 10 years since I wrote the answer? I know it worked when I wrote it because I had just solved exactly the problem OP was having.

Comment: This convention matches [PCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pcre), so I can't imagine that it changed. It's also possible the OP corrected it without a second thought.

Answer (score -2):

You can redirect through web config to
Hope it will help full

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
     <conditions>
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^abc.com$" />
     </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.abc.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```